# Moving to IasS on MS Azure

Tags: azure, iaas

We have got an application running fine on On premises and plan to move it to IaaS on Ms Azure, do we need to make any changes to it or will it work as is?

Comment: This is a very, very broad question.  What type of application is it?  Does it require a third party installation component that has licensing that prohibits deployment on a virtualized environment?  It would help if you better described what your application is and what makes up the moving pieces.  Apps can just be moved, but many times there are sometimes technical, and non-technical, aspects that cause problems.  It might help if you read up on things like http://wag.codeplex.com/ for brownfield development and then come back and ask specific questions for things that might not work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above post. You have not detailed if you are using Virtual Machines (Sql server or going to use Azure SQL). You will have to make choices about fail-over and geo redundancy, cloud services, etc. There are IP restrictions that may affect you (I don't know since I am not sure what you are moving). More than anything, I always warn people about the cost, it is difficult to understand. Here is an article series I wrote on Azure & SharePoint, you can skip the SharePoint stuff but the cost/limitation/VMs and such would still apply.

http://www.matthewjbailey.com/sharepoint-azure-guide/

Answer (score 0):

We've managed a lift-and-shift of an on-premise Windows app into Azure, but I wouldn't say it's been without its pain.  The above comments definitely ring true; you need to provide a bit more of an overview of what the current application does so that people can help answer your question.

In my experience, the only stumbling blocks to moving on-premise into Azure are:

1. Hardware requirements; i.e. if your application requires some specific hardware
2. Cost: It's not always cheaper to move large systems into Azure
3. Licensing: Make sure that your existing licensing is compatible with a cloud system which you don't control